# Convergent net which is not Cauchy

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, uniform-spaces, nets

The proof of the result that every [convergent net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Limits_of_nets) in a [uniform space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) is [Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Cauchy_nets), employs symmetry of the uniform space. A quasi-uniform space lacks that symmetry. Is it possible then to find a convergent net in a quasi-uniform space which is not Cauchy?

Comment: Posted also at MO: [Convergent net in a quasi-uniform space which is not Cauchy](https://mathoverflow.net/q/282429)